# The compiler can't find `um` in `winapi`

Tags: winapi, rust

I am working on a rust project and trying to get Winapi working.
This is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "sacl"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
winapi = "0.3.5"
```

And this is my `main.rs`:

```
extern crate winapi;

use winapi::um::winnt::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

But for some reason whenever I run `cargo build` I get the following error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `um` in `winapi`
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
3 | use winapi::um::winnt::*;
  |
```

I have tried including `um` as a feature in Cargo.toml since I read that winapi features are gated. Not finding anything about errors with `um`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `winapi::um::winnt` you have to include the feature `winnt` in your Cargo.toml.

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3.5", features = ["winnt"] }
```

The crate uses the last module name as the feature name. So for `winapi::winrt::activation` you would use `activation` for the feature.

**Appendix cross compilation:**

The modules of `winapi` are only available if `cfg(windows)` is present due to its [conditional compilation](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/0.3.6/src/lib.rs#L7). If you target windows but write the source code on a different platform, make sure to setup cross compilation as noted by *iceburg* in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Just tried this. Same error. Also tried with winuser.  

I know rust is cross-compiling, but is winapi an exception?  I am developing on Ubuntu (plan is to  run on a windows vm)

Comment: @iceburg How did you setup your cross compilation? Sadly I never used cross compilation in rust so I may be unable to help you for this case.

Comment: For cross compile, Ubuntu to Windows, i had to run these commands
-"rustup target add x86_64-pc-windows-gnu" #adds support cross compile
- "sudo apt-get install mingw-w64" # Needed for cross compile
- "cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu" #builds an exe

This actually helped solve my issue.  Apparently, WinAPI is only able to be built on windows installations, so for Ubuntu cross compilation is needed.  Thank you.